# Using Merge in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, merge, batch

I am relatively new to ModelBuilder.
I am trying a basic task using the merge function.
I have a folder which consists of a lot of shapefiles. Each shapefile from the folder needs to merge with file 'Punkte.shp' (if it is a point), 'Linien.shp'(if it is a line)  or to 'Flaeche.shp' (if it is a polygon).
What mistake have I made in my model? It is important that I get the output file with name (inputfile_) corresponding to the input file name from the data.
I tried with iterator (Iterate Datasets and Iterate feature class), both has shown error.
I have only Basic version of ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say your model logic is flawed. Look at the help file to see that the Merge tool takes a **LIST** of datasets as input. Your model is attempting to run the Merge tool on every loop of the iterator. This is a very inefficient way to run and will likely cause problems.

You need to read the help file and understand what the collect tool does and [sub-modelling](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/add-a-submodel-to-a-model.htm). There are many examples on this site.

I would have a sub-model that collects only the point data and creates a LIST of point datasets that feeds **ONCE** into a merge tool which is in the master model.